# Accessing Earthquake API in Android. UnknownHostException

Tags: java, android, http, url

I am just trying to access the Earthquake API and I am facing this error.

`03-22 00:55:27.805: W/System.err(1044): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "earthquake.usgs.gov": No address associated with hostname
03-22 00:55:27.815: W/System.err(1044):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:426)
03-22 00:55:27.815: W/System.err(1044):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
03-22 00:55:27.815: W/System.err(1044):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you given your application [the `INTERNET` permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) in its AndroidManifest.xml file?

You should have a line like the following in there:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```